# UI to show partial completion of a non-sequential process

Tags: usability, visual-design

How do I show that 1 out of 3 required users have approved a process if I can't show names and any user can approve in any order?

It's important to convey that user 2 doesn't have to wait for user 1 to authorise first.[image]

Comment: Why don't you write "1 out of 3 users have approved process X"?

Comment: agree I could do that but I was looking for a more visual to convey it. Like a progress tracker but non-linear or at least non-sequential

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a visual way to convey this information (not sure why it isn't clearer doing it with numbers), then you have to consider the visual icon or symbol and the status it may have.

Without going into the visual design element (since it has more to do with graphic design), you are looking at least two different strategies:

- using the visual icon as the count, so [x][ ][ ] approvals received
- using the visual icon and the status, so [x][-][-] approval status

Updated:

A particular visual design strategy that shows concurrent authorisation workflow (and the status)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Michael, I've added a sample of a few ideas I drafted. It might help to illustrate the problem a bit better. The hard bit is to differentiate the user "You" versus the other account holders as any of the 3 can authorise at any stage but we need all 3 for the process to be fully complete

Comment: @JohnnyPower not sure if this gives you some idea about how to fulfill those requirements visually.

Comment: Nice one Michael, yes that’s exactly what I was thinking. I did a very similar mock-up but yours is closer to what I need. Thanks so much!